# GetFileAttributes treat normal file as hidden file during frequent rename action

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am facing some issues with this function GetFileAttributes().

I am using C++ to get windows OS notifications and process them. For a particular case of frequent rename action on a single file, some times we are getting FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN for those file. I am using Windows 7 Profession Service Pack 1.

Assume I have a pdf file say test.pdf. We are monitoring a directory say (D:\Test) using automatic directory monitoring in windows os. I am renaming the file (D:\Test\test.pdf) frequently as test1.pdf, test12.pdf, test123.pdf and so on.
I got rename notifications for each of the above actions. We used to check the file attributes for each notifications and if it is hidden file, we won't process further. While checking the file attributes, some times it shows as FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN for the file. Is there any known issue with GetFileAttributes() ?

Is there any other thing I could try instead of GetFileAttributes ?

Comment: Are you sure that `GetFileAttributes` call doesn't in fact fail and return `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`? The latter has a numeric value of `DWORD(-1)`, that is, it has all bits set, including `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`. So if you don't check for `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` specifically, it will look like a hidden file.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Sorry for my delayed response. Thanks for your comments. In fact I didn't aware of that INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES also sets FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN bits. I will check for Invalid File Attributes and then for hidden file and post my results.